# How to draw a diagram using tikzcd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I was said that tikszcd is good library to draw commutative diagrams. So I tried to practize it by drawing the diagram in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383006/0-rightarrow-m-rightarrow-m-rightarrow-m-rightarrow-0-exact-m-flat/494914#494914 . But how can I get the arrow from zero to M''(x)N'? I tried

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}
& 0\arrow{d}\\
0\arrow{r} & M^\prime\otimes N^\prime
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

but it gave me mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions, one using `tikz-cd` the other using the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node`. I could adjust the position of the vertical arrows with `pst-node`, which  I don't know how to do with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
 & & & 0 \arrow{d}\\
0 \arrow{r} & M'\otimes N' \arrow{r}\arrow{d} & M\otimes N' \arrow{r}\arrow{d} & M''\otimes N' \arrow{r}\arrow{d} & 0\\%
0 \arrow{r} & M'\otimes N\arrow{r} & M\otimes N\arrow{r} & M''\otimes N \arrow{r} & 0 
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
 \usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

 \[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.25, linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=3pt, labelsep=2pt, rowsep=0.7cm, colsep = 1.1cm}
 \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
 \begin{psmatrix}
%%% nodes
 & & & 0\\
0 & M'\otimes N' & M\otimes N' & M''\otimes N'\hphantom{'} & 0\\%
0 & M'\otimes N\hphantom{'} & M\otimes N\hphantom{'} & M''\otimes N\hphantom{''} & 0
 %%% horizontal arrows
 \ncline{1,4}{2,4}
 \ncline{2,1}{2,2} \ncline{2,2}{2,3} \ncline{2,3}{2,4} \ncline{2,4}{2,5}
 \ncline{3,1}{3,2} \ncline{3,2}{3,3} \ncline{3,3}{3,4} \ncline{3,4}{3,5}
 %%% vertical arrows
 \ncline{1,4}{2,4}
  \ncline[offset=0.8pt]{2,2}{3,2} \ncline[offset=-0.6pt]{2,3}{3,3} \ncline[offset=0.6pt]{2,4}{3,4}
 \end{psmatrix}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. I only got package ifplatform Warning and package auto-pst-pdf Error.

Comment: @student: I forgot to say you can compile pstricks code with `pdflatex` if you set the switch `--enable-write18` ifd you're under MiKTeX, or `shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX), for the compiler.

Comment: @student If you only use the `tikz-cd` version, you don't need `\usepackage{pst-node}`. In my opinion this answer is not very well laid out: there should be the code for the `tikz-cd` version and the `pst-node` version should be in a separate example document.